# Keeping dictionary keys of JSON Object in order in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, key

I'm using the JSON-FRAMEWORK in objective C to parse a JSON object.
When I call [jsonString JSONValue], I get back a dictionary, but the keys aren't in the same order as the JSON Object I'm parsing. Is there anyway to keep this order the same?

Comment: Why would you need to keep the order the same?  It's a dictionary--accessing an element by key is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Because I have a separate object that has an index attribute. This index is supposed to correspond to the order in which keys are in in the json object. Since it appears to be the case that the dictionary's keys will be unordered, I guess I'll have to figure out a different way to make the connection between my object, and the key it should correspond to in the dictionary

Comment: Instead of an index you could simply store the dictionary key ...

Comment: Right. Or I might just pass in the index into the json object.

Comment: Um, the _whole point_ is that "index into the JSON object" is meaningless since JSON objects are _unordered_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In JSON objects, *by definition*, the order of the key-value pairs is not meaningful. The specification allows a JSON producer to permute them any way it want, even at random -- and does not require a parser to preserve the ordering. RFC 4627 says:

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
>      pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
>      boolean, null, object, or array.

If you need the ordering to be preserved, what you have is not JSON, but a home-defined format that just happens to look superficially like JSON.

Comment: maybe "happens to look superficially like" is a little harsh. It would act *mostly* like JSON, but would have a non-trivial difference.