# Parse JSON to ordered dictionary

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I am trying to parse a JSON which contains a dictionary like this:

`{"key1" : "value1", "key2" : "value2", "key3" : "value3", ..., "key_n", "value_n"}`.

I want to parse this JSON to a `Dictionary` in Swift, but the order is very important to keep. I know that Swift does not have any Ordered Dictionary type, but is there any way to overcome this?

Note that the JSON I'm parsing contains hundreds of keys and there's no value I can sort on (asc. / desc.) afterwards to recreate the order.

Comment: Why do you want to keep this order? How do you want to use this order afterwards?

Comment: The order will determine how information is displayed in my application. Imagine a FAQ page (for example) where the FAQs are fetched from a backend and the order of the questions are important.

Comment: Have a look at answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969688/ordered-dictionary-in-swift. I guess an array of tuples is what you need. You just need to parse your JSON to this format.

Comment: If you need a sorted list then the server should send a JSON array, not a dictionary.

Comment: If you control whatever is producing that JSON, change it to an array if order is important. Otherwise you cannot use standard JSON tools to work with that data (they won't preserve order).

Comment: @Puneet Sharma - Thank you very much! The problem with this solution is that when I parse the JSON object I will lose the order... I don't see how I can parse the JSON (Data object) to a "custom type".

Comment: @NikMos: You won't be able to do that with the standard JSON parsers, you'd have to roll your own (or dig really deep into the internals of the parser to get the raw tokens). Ideally, change to send an array.

Comment: @Martin R - That would be the easiest way for me (not all the other clients who happens to support ordered dictionary). But I get your point... Thank you!

Comment: To keep existing clients happy, you could make a different endpoint for the array-version. Should be a thin layer server-side, not too much trouble.

Comment: Same question for Objective-C (which could have been useful for you if there was an answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198412/keeping-dictionary-keys-of-json-object-in-order-in-objective-c

Comment: @Thilo You are right... I was hoping that the ordered dictionary was possible, but it seems that it would be very difficult. Maybe I'll try experimenting with it at some point, and I'll share my experience here.

Comment: Note that both http://json.org and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 define a JSON object as an *unordered* collection of  name/value pairs.

Comment: @Thilo I get that it conflicts with the idea of hashing. I was thinking that maybe I could parse the Data object to my own type, so I get the raw data and then make my own type. Thank you very much for all your input! I appreciate it!

Comment: @NikMos: Yes, you can. But it's a lot of work, and just digging your hole deeper. Using your custom almost-JSON format reduces interoperability for no good reason.